# Have X11 c program compiled, getting undefined reference errors, what lib(s) are needed?

Tags: linux, gcc, build, xlib

I am new to c programming on Linux.  My objective is to create an efficient program to monitor free space on a mounted partition (parm1) and put an icon in the tray to represent it showing my name (parm2) for it and the percentage of free space (script to calculate parm3), run that script every xxx seconds (parm4) and refresh the icon if the value changes (icon filename parm5).

For starters I have just copied a sample c program from here and am just trying to get it to compile and run as is, to embed a program with an icon in the tray.

[freedesktop XEmbed systray client code in C, Xlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392284/freedesktop-xembed-systray-client-code-in-c-xlib)

I tweaked it to incorporate suggested changes and remove errors, and it compiles clean, but appears to need lib(s) added to be able to create an executable.

How do I find out what libraries are needed, and what order to put them in?

```
/* from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392284/freedesktop-xembed-systray-client-code-in-c-xlib */ 

#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MIN(A, B)               ((A) < (B) ? (A) : (B))

/* --------- XEMBED and systray stuff */
#define SYSTEM_TRAY_REQUEST_DOCK   0
#define SYSTEM_TRAY_BEGIN_MESSAGE   1
#define SYSTEM_TRAY_CANCEL_MESSAGE  2

int usleep(useconds_t useconds); //pass in microseconds

static int trapped_error_code = 0;
static int (*old_error_handler) (Display *, XErrorEvent *);

static int
error_handler(Display     *display, XErrorEvent *error) {
    trapped_error_code = error->error_code;
    return 0;
}

void
trap_errors(void) {
    trapped_error_code = 0;
    old_error_handler = XSetErrorHandler(error_handler);
}

int
untrap_errors(void) {
    XSetErrorHandler(old_error_handler);
    return trapped_error_code;
}

void
send_systray_message(Display* dpy, long message, long data1, long data2, long data3) {
    XEvent ev;

    Atom selection_atom = XInternAtom (dpy,"_NET_SYSTEM_TRAY_S0",False);
    Window tray = XGetSelectionOwner (dpy,selection_atom);

    if ( tray != None)
        XSelectInput (dpy,tray,StructureNotifyMask);

    memset(&ev, 0, sizeof(ev));
    ev.xclient.type = ClientMessage;
    ev.xclient.window = tray;
    ev.xclient.message_type = XInternAtom (dpy, "_NET_SYSTEM_TRAY_OPCODE", False );
    ev.xclient.format = 32;
    ev.xclient.data.l[0] = CurrentTime;
    ev.xclient.data.l[1] = message;
    ev.xclient.data.l[2] = data1; // <--- your window is only here
    ev.xclient.data.l[3] = data2;
    ev.xclient.data.l[4] = data3;

    trap_errors();
    XSendEvent(dpy, tray, False, NoEventMask, &ev);
    XSync(dpy, False);
    usleep(10000);
    if (untrap_errors()) {
        /* Handle errors */
    }
}

/* ------------ Regular X stuff */
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int width, height;
    XWindowAttributes wa;
    XEvent ev;
    Display *dpy;
    int screen;
    Window root, win;

    /* init */
    if (!(dpy=XOpenDisplay(NULL)))
        return 1;
    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, screen);
    if(!XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, root, &wa))
        return 1;
    width = height = MIN(wa.width, wa.height);

    /* create window */
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dpy, root, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 0xFFFF9900);

    /* call send_systray_messsage */
    send_systray_message(dpy, SYSTEM_TRAY_REQUEST_DOCK, win, 0, 0); // pass win only once

    XMapWindow(dpy, win);

    XSync(dpy, False);

    /* run */
    while(1) {
        while(XPending(dpy)) {
            XNextEvent(dpy, &ev); /* just waiting until we error because window closed */
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ gcc xmbed_system_tray.c -o xmbed_system_tray 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccs2ZnYg.o: in function `trap_errors':
xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `XSetErrorHandler'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccs2ZnYg.o: in function `untrap_errors':
xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `XSetErrorHandler'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccs2ZnYg.o: in function `send_systray_message':
xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0xa8): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `XGetSelectionOwner'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `XSelectInput'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x1ab): undefined reference to `XSendEvent'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x1bf): undefined reference to `XSync'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccs2ZnYg.o: in function `main':
xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to `XGetWindowAttributes'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x2b2): undefined reference to `XCreateSimpleWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `XMapWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x2fe): undefined reference to `XSync'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to `XNextEvent'
/usr/bin/ld: xmbed_system_tray.c:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `XPending'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any videos that showed anything, but I did find a site where he shows possible libraries or maybe locations.  Therefore, I am guessing that either my environment is setup wrong so it can't find what it's looking for, or what it's looking for isn't installed.

http://mech.math.msu.su/~nap/2/GWindow/xintro.html

That didn't help, but I eventually found another page that did at:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X_Window_Programming/Xlib

Their sample program had compile instructions:

```
To Compile: gcc -O2 -Wall -o test test.c -L /usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lm
```

So for mine I tried:

```
gcc -o xmbed_system_tray xmbed_system_tray.c -lX11
```

By removing options one at a time I found the -lX11 parameter not being there before was causing the failure, and now the executable gets created and will run.

The program only consumes about 1 mb of memory compared to 25 to 35 mb for the other programs I found capable of running a program in the tray.